# Problema con reloj de Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este codigo el cual hace un reloj en Javascript. El único problema que tengo es que no agarra el uso horario correctamente y le resta 30 minutos a la hora y le suma una hora.

Logre arreglar lo de la hora que se suma demas, pero no logró arreglar los 30 minutos extra porque si le sumo los 30 minutos, el reloj muestra la hora mal.

Mi horario es UTC-4

Aqui dejo mi codigo

```js
window.onload = date_time('date_time');


function date_time(id) {
  date = new Date; <!-- Obtiene el dia -->
  year = date.getFullYear();
  month = date.getMonth();
  months = new Array('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
  d = date.getDate();
  day = date.getDay();
  days = new Array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado');
  h = date.getHours() - 1;
  var session = "AM";

  if (h < 10) <!-- Si la hora es menor a 10, se le anade un 0 a la izquierda -->
  {
    h = "0" + h;
  }

  if (h >= 12 && session == "AM") {
    h = h - 11;
    session = "PM";
  }

  m = date.getMinutes();
  if (m < 10) <!-- Si los minutos son menores a 10, se le anade un 0 a la izquierda -->
  {
    m = "0" + m;
  }

  s = date.getSeconds();
  if (s < 10) <!-- Si los segundos son menores a 10, se le anade un 0 a la izquierda -->
  {
    s = "0" + s;
  }

  result = '' + days[day] + ',' + ' ' + d + ' ' + 'de ' + months[month] + ' ' + 'del' + ' ' + year + '' + ', ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
  setTimeout('date_time("' + id + '");', '1000');
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("imagenes/fondo_une.jpg")
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center><span id="date_time"></span></center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**intentalo asi:**

regresando los valores a su estado normal.
te agrege la opcion 2 que es para el format del `toLocaleString` pasandole un `timezone` deseado en mi ejemplo `America/Bogota`.

```js
window.onload = date_time();

function date_time() {

date = new Date();
year = date.getFullYear();

month = date.getMonth();
months = new Array('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
d = date.getDate();
day = date.getDay();
days = new Array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado');
var session = "AM";

h = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2); 
m = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
s = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

if (h >= 12) {
    h = h - 11;
    session = "PM";
}

result = `${days[day]}, ${d} de ${months[month]} del  ${year},  ${h}:${m}:${s} ${session}`;


time  = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Bogota', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',hour12: true });
result2 = `version 2: ${days[day]}, ${d} de ${months[month]} del  ${year}, ${time}`;

document.getElementById("date_time").innerText = result;
document.getElementById("date_time2").innerText = result2;
setTimeout(date_time, '1000');
return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("imagenes/fondo_une.jpg")
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center><span id="date_time"></span></center>
   <center><span id="date_time2"></span></center>
</body>
```

**referencia:**
[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)